# What is the best way to get the computer name remotely based on an IP address?

Tags: windows, ip-address, netbios

I have several windows machines identified by ip address. I would like to write an application that query the computers remotely and gets their name. I cannot rely on DNS because it does not provide exact results.

I heard that there is a NetBIOS API that can be used, but I am not familiar with this API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check [getnameinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738532(VS.85).aspx)

The getnameinfo function provides protocol-independent name resolution from an address to an ANSI host name and from a port number to the ANSI service name.

Comment: I will try this suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
PING -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This will try WINS and then DNS.

The `NSLOOKUP` command does similar, but only via DNS.

Comment: @Jay, Is WINS more reliable than the DNS lookup? I have bad experience with DNS

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 if I used the lowercase `ping -a x.x.x.x` syntax. `-A` was not recognized on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact purpose of RARP or [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

On Windows there is a dll (DHCPobj.dll) available in one of the Microsoft resource kits that supposedly allows you to make queries like this to your local DHCP server. I've never played with it, so I can't say for sure how well it works.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below command to get youre remote host name using ip address

```
nslookup [ip address]
```

or you can use

```
tracert [ip address]
```

to track route that that specific ip address